# Can I have docs in a SharePoint Library open the same window?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint library that has PDF files uploaded with the library.  I uploaded each doc to not open in a separate window.  However, the requirements would like the PDF file to open in the page with the header, footer.

Similar to an inline page when doing HTML, how can I add this to my out of the box library page?

The library is using the ListViewWebPart.

If you need additional information please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Angela,

I don't think its Out of the box available in SharePoint...

You will need to use a PDF Viewer Control such as:
[PDF Viewer in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re)
[Another one](http://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/pdf-viewer-in-asp-net/)

You will need to make a Visual Web Part for this and add the HyperLink field that takes to the page where this control is used! That is how you can have different web parts, for header and footer you can use Content Editor Web Parts and in Middle Web Part Zone you can drop Visual Web Part...

Quite too much work isn't it?